# Does MS VS 2003 support MC55?

Tags: windows-mobile, sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2003

I tried to run MS VS 2003 project on MC55. I got this error below -

> There were deployment errors. Continue?

Does MS VS 2003 support MC55? How about SQL compact CRUD operation? Please share me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [the MC55](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Mobile+Computers/Handheld+Computers/MC55_US-EN) runs Windows Mobile (or Windows Embedded Handheld) 6.5.  Visual Studio 2003 was released long before this version of Windows Mobile and the connectivity pieces have changed since then.  It also probably ships with Compact Framework 2.0 or later, which Studio 2003 doesn't support.

So the short answer is no, this is not a supported scenario.

Comment: For information only the MC55 can be downgraded to WM 6.1 but as far as I know doesn't change ctacke's conclusions.